# trying to free allocated memory generate heap error

Tags: c, malloc, free, heap-corruption

I'm dealing with a strange errors in code which i wrote in c.
this is the place where the error occur:

```
    char* firstChar = (char*) malloc(ONE_CHAR_STRING);
if (!firstChar) {
    *result = MTM_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    return false;
}
if (command != NULL) {
    strcpy(firstChar, command);
    firstChar[1] = '\0';
}
free(firstChar);
```

'command' is a string, and ONE_CHAR_STRING defines in the program, (ONE_CHAR_STRING= 2).
the error which appear when the program get into the 'free' function is:

```
warning: Heap block at 00731528 modified at 00731532 past requested size of 2
```

this error strangely append  only on my PC/eclipse on windows. when i run the code in linux it doesn't prompt this error and works(the specific part) fine.
what could be the reason?

another question again about memory errors, how it is possibly that my program(without this part) works fine on windows, but in linux their is a problem in one of my memory allocations?
I can't write down here the code cause it's too long (and gdb doesn't gives me the lines of where the error occur).. the question is about the possibility and what could be the reasons for it.

Thanks, Almog.

Comment: if `ONE_CHAR_STRING==2`, you have only allocated enough storage for a 1 character `command` (plus the nul terminator).  If `command` is longer, the `strcpy` will write beyond the memory you have allocated, resulting in undefined behaviour.  Some platforms may notice and report this; others may appear to work, only to crash later due to this memory corruption.

Comment: Assuming `command` is a valid string, you'd be better off just doing `firstChar[0] = command[0]; firstChar[1] = 0;`, because thats the only way this doesn't invoke undefined behavior if `command` is longer than a single char null-term string. And "doesn't prompt this error" under Linux is the ruthless reality of undefined behavior. Its *undefined*, and may (unluckily) actually "work". Be glad you ran it under conditions that fostered the error.

Comment: What are the contents of `command`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use another string copy function to avoid overflow:

`strncpy(firstChar,command,ONE_CHAR_STRING);`

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` may overlap to copy `firstChar` if `command` string length is greater than `ONE_CHAR_STRING` or not null terminated that lead you to strange behavior. You can safely copy `command` string to `firstChar` by assign `firstChar[0] = command[0]; firstChar[1] = '\0'`

If your compiler for both Linux and Windows is `gcc` (MinGW in Windows) use `-fstack-protector` as compiler parameter to help you to debug function such as `strcpy` buffer overflow.